# How to output the current date and time of a particular country?

Tags: date-and-time

When you run Date, it outputs information about the date and time set on my computer.

```
Date[]
```

If I modify them, the output results will also be different.

How to express the current perspective of a particular country?

Comment: Are you asking about timezones and time offsets?

Comment: For example, I would like to get the current date and time of Canada.  And, even if I change the date and time on my computer, I want to get the actual date and time of the country where I live.

Comment: Some countries have multiple time zones...

Comment: Your code is not the result I want. If I change the time on my computer to 2020, the above result will also change to 2020.

Comment: You can probably find an API that will give you the current data/time. Just call it from your Mathematica code with URLExecute (or other related functions). I haven't actually tried it, but maybe `http://worldtimeapi.org`

Comment: `cities = GatherBy[CityData[{Large, "Canada"}], #["TimeZone"]["OffsetFromUTC"] &]; Prepend[ReverseSortBy[{#[[1]]["TimeZone"]["OffsetFromUTC"], Row[Take[#, UpTo[3]]]} & /@ cities, First], {"OffsetFromUTC", "city"}] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the opinion you gave me above,
I solved it as follows. Thank you all for the heat.

```
"datetime"/.Import[URL["http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Seoul"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

TimeZoneConvert[DateObject[Date[]], "Asia/Seoul"]

Comment: Your answer already was posted and then deleted, because "The problem as I understood it is that Now isn’t necessarily “now” on OP’s machine".  In other words, the OP wants a solution that does not rely on the time as determined by the computer's internal clock.